# Using Vaadin Flow with Jakarta EE 9

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I see that [Apache Tomcat 10](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi) (alpha) is now available. The major feature there is support for [Jakarta EE](https://jakarta.ee) 9 where package names for APIs have changed from [javax.*](http://APIs%20has%20changed%20from%20javax.*%20to%20jakarta.*) to [jakarta.*](http://APIs%20has%20changed%20from%20javax.*%20to%20jakarta.*). Jakarta EE 9 now has a [milestone release](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jakartaee-platform/jakartaee9/JakartaEE9) available.

Can the current versions of Vaadin Flow (14 or 16) be made to work with the new Jakarta 9 and its name changes?

Comment: What problems did you face trying it?

Comment: @cfrick I have not tried it. I know a Vaadin project has a dependency on [javax.servlet-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api) which is using the old `javax` naming. So I assume that being a servlet means Vaadin has code referring to code in a package that will not be available on a Jakarta server such as Tomcat 10.

Comment: As for the vote to close because "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more 1", I made no such request. The tools and software libraries are at hand: Vaadin Flow & Jakarta EE 9.

Comment: Vaadin does not run on Tomcat 10 because of the package renaming. Why don't you open an issue on https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vaadin does currently not support Jakarta EE 9 because of the package name changes. We're watching to see how the situation develops to e.g. see whether application servers would include helpers to automatically also support parts that use the old package names.

In the mean time, you can try applying those changes manually using e.g. https://github.com/apache/tomcat-jakartaee-migration or https://github.com/eclipse/transformer/.